# .htaccess need help to serve requests to index.php in non root folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have a specific website structure:

`root:`

```
styles.css
pages/index.html
folder_with_assets_1
folder_with_assets_2
folder_with_images
```

I've renamed `index.html` to `index.php` in order to get rid of `.html` extension in the URL

But the problem is that `index.php` is located not in a root folder, it's in `pages` folder.
Which right `.htaccess` rules could solve the problem in order to redirect requests to `pages` folder?

**UPDATE**
the screenshot with folder structure:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is your htaccess located? And how did you rename the index file via ftp rename  or via htaccess rule?

Comment: I haven't placed `.htaccess` yet, but it should be placed in root folder. I've renamed through a FTP.

Comment: Okay, so you want to redirect all URLs to the index.php file that's located inside a subdirectory?

Comment: Yes, as I can't move `index` file outside subfolder to the root. The markup will simply break, as there are a lot of paths already defined with `js` and other `css` files.

Comment: "I've renamed index.html to index.php in order to get rid of .html extension in the URL" - ?! So, what you've listed as `pages/index.html` in your file structure is really `pages/index.php`? (Although you don't need to physically change the file extension in order to remove the file extension?) Do your "page" URLs follow any particular format?

Comment: I've rename `pages/index.html` to `pages/index.php` as it's plain HTML file, doesn't make any sense to me. It's "onepage" website format with plenty of JS and CSS. There are only local URLs pointing to sections (href tag) and AJAX call to specific PHP files

Comment: "doesn't make any sense to me." - Exactly, it doesn't look like changing the file extension actually serves any purpose in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the face of it, this just looks a standard front-controller pattern. Whether the front-controller is located inside a subdirectory or directly in the document root is largely irrelevant - the process is the same.

Assuming you are using the `.htaccess` file in the document root and there is no discernable pattern to the *page* URLs...

For example, using mod_dir `FallbackResource`:

```
FallbackResource /pages/index.php
```

Or, using mod_rewrite:

```
DirectoryIndex /pages/index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (^|/)index\.php - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . pages/index.php [L]
```

---

**UPDATE#1:**

> It's "onepage" website format with plenty of JS and CSS. There are only local URLs pointing to sections (href tag) and AJAX call to specific PHP files

In that case, it just looks like you need to change the `DirectoryIndex` - you don't need a front-controller pattern (as discussed above) at all.

For example:

```
DirectoryIndex /pages/index.php
```

Now, a request for the "homepage", ie the document root `https://example.com/` will serve `/pages/index.php`.

---

**UPDATE#2:**

From your screenshot, it looks like directory listings (mod_autoindex) are enabled. These should be disabled at the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes
```

---

**UPDATE#3:**

From your screenshot, it would seem that what you have called "root" in your file structure is not actually your website's "document root", since you are accessing this location via a `/test` subdirectory, ie. `localhost/test/`. The directives above are assuming these files are located in the "document root", ie. `localhost/` and there is no `/test` subdirectory. (Which I expect is how it is structured on your "live" environment?)

If your `.htaccess` file is located in the `/test` subdirectory and you are requesting `localhost/test/` (as per your screenshot) then you will need to adjust this accordingly:

For example:

```
DirectoryIndex /test/pages/index.php
```

However, that will not work on the live site (assuming you don't have a `/test` subdirectory on live). Instead, you can simply omit the slash prefix, to make it *relative*.

For example:

```
DirectoryIndex pages/index.php
```

This should work OK in your case since you have a SPA (just a homepage URL).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's strange, but my XAMPPdoesn't react to changes... I've posted the screenshot in my first post

Comment: @Kuzma Actually, from your update in comments, it sounds like you just need to change the `DirectoryIndex` (in my updated answer). You don't need the front-controller pattern (in your screenshot).

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications! Unfortunately, it's still doesn't work. I've updated `.htaccess` with `Options -Indexes DirectoryIndex /pages/index.php`. But I get error 403 - `Access forbidden!`. Can't check it on a live website to exclude a possible misconfiguration, I'm testing it locally. But my XAMPP setup is mostly with default settings...

Comment: @kuzma Ah, from your screenshot it looks like your files are located in a `/test` subdirectory, not the "document root". In this case you will need to remove the slash prefix from the `DirectoryIndex pages/index.php`  directive. Presumably your live website does not use a `/test` subdirectory, so would not have had this problem.

Comment: Thank you for explanation!

Comment: @Kuzma You're welcome.